# React Native DRY Javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native

1) I have a specific implementation where I want to adhere to the DRY principles.
The structure of both the methods is almost exactly the same. I am wondering if this is a way not to repeat the implementation:

```
addCardToExistingCustomer(cardDetail){
    PaymentUtil.stripeCreateCardToken(cardDetail).then((cardTokenResult)=>{
      if(cardTokenResult.error){
        console.log("There was an error with the card!");

      } else {
          PaymentUtil.addCardToExistingCustomer(cardTokenResult.id).then((card) =>{


          });  
      }
    });
  }  

  addCardToNewCustomer(cardDetail){
    this.stripeCreateCardToken(cardDetail).then((cardTokenResult)=>{
      if(cardTokenResult.error){
        console.log("There was an error with the card!");

      } else {
        console.log("Successfully created card token");
        PaymentUtil.stripeCreateCustomer(cardTokenResult.id)

      }
    });
  }
```

2) Is this the best way to chain promises ? Specifically how should you handle exceptions from the promises in the chain which aren't the last element of the chain.

Say for example promise `getStripeCustomerId` rejected. How should you handle the the rejection.

```
addCardToExistingCustomer(cardTokenResultId){
    return this.getStripeCustomerId(userDetail).then((customerId) => {
            return  this.removeAllExistingCards(userDetail).then(()=>{
                    return  Stripe.addCardToCustomer(cardTokenResultId,customerId);
            });
        });     
},


getStripeCustomerId(userDetail){
    return FirebaseRESTUtil.getStripeCustomer(userDetail.username)
        .then((fbStripe) => (fbStripe.customerId)); 
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1- This way can be better.. It will use promises chains to work on data.

```
getCardTokenResult(cardDetail) {
  return PaymentUtil.stripeCreateCardToken(cardDetail)
    .then((cardTokenResult) => {
      if(cardTokenResult.error){
        return Promise.reject('There was an error with the card!!');
      } else {
        return cardTokenResult;
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error)):
}

addCardToExistingCustomer(cardDetail){
  return getCardTokenResult(cardDetail)
    .then((cardTokenResult) => {
      PaymentUtil.addCardToExistingCustomer(cardTokenResult.id).then((card) =>{
        // do something
      });
    });
}

addCardToNewCustomer(cardDetail){
  return getCardTokenResult(cardDetail)
    .then((cardTokenResult) => {
      PaymentUtil.stripeCreateCustomer(cardTokenResult.id);
    });
}
```

2- You can use **catch** to get errors on Promises chain. You can look the code above. I added catch to get cardtokenresult error. You can continue same way on chain to get other errors.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you're checking for errors in the first argument of your `then`. I'm pretty sure this is incorrect as Stripe does not return HTTP 200 status on errors.

Having said that, I like to flatten chained promises instead of nesting them because I find that it makes the code easier to maintain and read:

```
addCardToExistingCustomer(cardTokenResultId) {
    return this.getStripeCustomerId(userDetail).then((customerId) => {
        return this.removeAllExistingCards(userDetail); // returns a promise
    }).then(() => {
        return Stripe.addCardToCustomer(cardTokenResultId,customerId); // returns a promise
    });     
},
```

Now any errors will bubble up to the main outer promise, so you can check for errors by

```
addCardToExistingCustomer(myId).then(() => { 
        console.log('success!');
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```